# ifndef with multiple AND conditions in makefile gnu

Tags: makefile, ifndef

How do I ensure that `make` command has the parameter `ENV` passed in it?

Eg: `make destroy ENV=test` if ENV is not passed I should throw error.

Code:

```
ENV ?=prod
ifndef ENV
   $(error ENV is not defined, Please provide ENV paramter in your make command)
ifndef FORCE
   @/bin/echo -n "Are you sure to DESTROY configuration for ${ENV}? [y/N] " && read ans && [ $${ans:-N} = y ]
endif
endif
   terraform destroy ${ARGS}
```

Comment: The documentation will tell you what you can do in `ifdef` / `ifndef`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html

Comment: There are plenty of functions in GNU Make that you can use as part of the condition that will let you check other things as with "and", even including short-circuiting.  But with a very generic statement of CONDITION1 / CONDITION2 as you've provided it's hard to explain which ones to use or how to use them.  If you would like specific help please provide specific examples.

Comment: @MadScientist I have updated my code and added some information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is whether you want to test whether they are empty, or whether they are defined.   If you want to test that at least one is set to a non-empty value, you can use the following trick:

```
ifeq ($(CONDITION1)$(CONDITION2),)
# Both CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 are empty or not defined
endif
```

If you want to test if either is defined (but potentially emtpy), you could would use the [origin](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html) function:

```
ifeq ($(origin CONDITION1)$(origin CONDITION2),undefinedundefined)
# Both CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 are not defined
endif
```

For more complex expressions, you can also use the `$(if ...)`, `$(and ...)` and `$(or ...)` functions (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html)).   eg:

```
ifeq ($(or $(CONDITION1),$(CONDITION2)),)
# Both CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 are empty or not defined
endif
```

---

EDIT:

As to the updated question, it is a bit different than what you were originally asking.  The cleanest way to do this is to add the checks in a recipe rather than conditional parts of the make:

```
checkenv:
   @[ "$(origin ENV)" -eq "command line" ] \
       || echo "ERROR ENV not defined on command line" >&2 \
       && false
   @[ $(FORCE) ] \
       || echo -n "Are you sure to DESTROY configuration for ${ENV}? [y/N]" \
       && read ans \
       && [ $${ans:-N} = y ] 

maintarget: checkenv
    terraform destroy ${ARGS}
```

Comment: this is something detailed answer. thank you so much! however, my question sound different earlier. so i have updated my it again. could you take a look?

Comment: You can use `$(origin V)` to differentiate if `V` came from command line, or environment, etc.   I'll update the answer to your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Make doesn't support that. You can nest them. That has the same effect

```
ifndef CONDITION1
ifndef CONDITION2
<do something>
endif
endif
<do nothing>
```

Comment: If I want to check CONDITION1 first if success then I want to run CONDITION2 or it should throw error. How do we do that in Make